# Django Rest Framework Custom Permission does not recognize user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I am trying to enforce a custom permission in DRF. Specifically, I am trying to see whether a user is authorized to access an object. I adapted this solution from another post here but it does not quite work for me. The permission class always assumes that request.user is an Anonymous user. What am I missing?

**permissions.py**

```
class CanSeeWishlist(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        try:
            wishlist = Wishlist.objects.get(
                pk=view.kwargs['pk'])
        except:
            return False

        if wishlist.private:
            print(request.user) # Prints Anonymous User
            if request.user.id == wishlist.owner.id or request.user.id in wishlist.members.all():
                return True
            return False
        return True
```

**api.py**

```
class WishlistViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = WishlistSerializer
    queryset = Wishlist.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
    ]

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            self.permission_classes = (CanSeeWishlist,)
        return super(WishlistViewset, self).get_permissions()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that doing  `super(WishlistViewset, self).get_permissions()` didn't pass `request` to the class so it resulted in `Anonymous User` or as you dropped `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` something went wrong.

Anyway, I think it's better to override `get_permissions()` with the same way it was implemented, it will fix the problem I hope:

What `get_permissions()` actually do:

```
def get_permissions(self):
        """
        Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
        """
        return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```

So It should be:

```
def get_permissions(self):
        permissions_list = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly] #the base one that should be there for all request actions
        if self.request.method == 'GET': # this will add the permission for all GET requests, If you want it to only apply on retrive you can do self.action == 'retrive':
            permissions_list.append(CanSeeWishlist)
        return [permission() for permission in permissions_list]
```